# How do I filter an object by object keys and values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, filter

I have two arrays, one is a filter with a key and value, and one data.

```js
const filter = [
   {key: "name", value: "foo"},
   {key: "url", value: "foobar.com"}
]

const data = [
   {name: "foo", url: "google.com", extra: "hello!"}, 
   {name: "foo", url: "foobar.com", extra: "hello!"}, 
   {name: "bar", url: "foobar.com", extra: "hello!"},
   {name: "foo", url: "foobar.com", extra: "goodbye!"}
]
```

I want to achieve a one-line filter option that does the following:

```js
const filteredData = data. //doSomething();

console.log(filteredData) 

/** prints out: 
 * [{name: "foo", url: "foobar.com", extra: "hello!"},{name: "foo", url: "foobar.com", extra: "goodbye!"}]
 **/
```

The filter array is a dynamically changing list of keys and values. Currently, I have the `name` and `url` hardcoded through two **[Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** constants which check explicitly for the type and value, but I know for expandability and best practices, this isn't ideal. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Array.filter()` to iterate the `data` items. Iterate the `filter` with `Array.every()`, and check if each value of the current items matches the respective filter value.

```js
const fn = (arr, filter) => arr.filter(o => 
  filter.every(({ key, value }) => o[key] === value)
) 

const filter = [{"key":"name","value":"foo"},{"key":"url","value":"foobar.com"}]

const data = [{"name":"foo","url":"google.com","extra":"hello!"},{"name":"foo","url":"foobar.com","extra":"hello!"},{"name":"bar","url":"foobar.com","extra":"hello!"},{"name":"foo","url":"foobar.com","extra":"goodbye!"}]

const result = fn(data, filter)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to iterate over `data` array, and [`.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to check the matching of the current item with `filter` conditions:

```js
const filter = [
   {key: "name", value: "foo"},
   {key: "url", value: "foobar.com"}
];
const data = [
   {name: "foo", url: "google.com", extra: "hello!"}, 
   {name: "foo", url: "foobar.com", extra: "hello!"}, 
   {name: "bar", url: "foobar.com", extra: "hello!"},
   {name: "foo", url: "foobar.com", extra: "goodbye!"}
];

const filteredData = data.filter(item =>
   filter.every(({key,value}) => item[key]===value)
);

console.log(filteredData)
```